# Make captcha appear after 10s

Tags: javascript, captcha

I want to make my captcha appear after waiting 10 seconds; how can this be done?

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: Help you? Of course! What have you tried? Have you read how to delay a function by some time?

Comment: Probably. What's your specific question?

Comment: Magic.  That's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jQuery. By showing the `div` enclosing your captcha after 10 seconds

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#captcha_div').show();
}, 10000 //10 seconds
);`
```

Hope it helps...!